# Why a Dojo app could be trying to retrieve files erroneously from googleapis in Firefox and not in Chrome?

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, dojo

I'm maintaining an old PHP app that is using Dojo. On Chrome all load well but on Firefox four  "404 Not Found" error happened in a loop. The error happens while Firefox try to get the following files:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.1/src/namespaces/dojo.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.1/src/namespaces.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.1/src/__package__.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.1/src.js
```

I said a loop because after the last error, Firefox try to get the [first one](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.1/src/namespaces/dojo.js) again, then the [second one](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.1/src/namespaces.js) again and so on infinitely.

What can be causing such estrange behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this could sound odd, but after disable the [Awesome Screenshot Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/awesome-screenshot-capture-/) Firefox Add-On the problem disappear.

I get to this solution because beside this strange problem, I saw some request to superfish.com while accessing to the pages of this application, and that hasn't sense. Some guys over there said that such requests to superfish.com could related with the presence of  some Add-On, then, I begin to disable Add-On until find out what was the problematic Add-On.

I hope this can help some body that get in my same situation.